# Hyperlink of Branding Image in NSIS

Tags: nsis

I have the following question - is it possible to define a link for the branding image in NSIS, so that the user would be able to click on the image and open a web page in a browser? If possible, how is to be done? Thanks for the help in advance.

Regards,
Al

Comment: Which image are we talking about? MUI welcome or header or a custom image?

Comment: Nope, I wasn't able to find anything that suggests that specifying a hyperlink in a branding image is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to find anything that suggests that specifying a hyperlink in a branding image is possible. Eventually I abandoned it.

Comment: There is no built in support for this, but it would probably be possible with a plugin.